# The "handle" function and Real World Haskell

Tags: compiler-errors, haskell

I'm reading RWH, and I've come to chapter 9. It introduces the following piece of code:

```
import System.IO
import Control.Exception

saferFileSize :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe Integer)
saferFileSize path = handle (\_ -> return Nothing) $ do
  h <- openFile path ReadMode
  size <- hFileSize h
  hClose h
  return (Just size)
```

It won't compile however, giving the following error message:

```
test.hs:5:22:
    Ambiguous type variable `e0' in the constraint:
      (Exception e0) arising from a use of `handle'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: handle (\ _ -> return Nothing)
    In the expression:
      handle (\ _ -> return Nothing)
      $ do { h <- openFile path ReadMode;
             size <- hFileSize h;
             hClose h;
             return (Just size) }
    In an equation for `saferFileSize':
        saferFileSize path
          = handle (\ _ -> return Nothing)
            $ do { h <- openFile path ReadMode;
                   size <- hFileSize h;
                   hClose h;
                   .... }
```

What is going wrong here? Why won't it compile?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not too long after RWH came out, the exception interface was changed to support more flexible handlers where the type of the handler determines which exceptions it will catch. E.g. a handler which takes `SomeException` will catch anything (not usually a good idea), while a handler that takes `IOException` will only catch IO exceptions.

As a consequence of this, it's easy to run into ambiguity problems with "do-nothing" handlers like the one in your example, since the compiler can't infer what type of exceptions you're trying to catch. An easy way of fixing this is to provide a type signature for your handler function.

```
handle ((\_ -> return Nothing) :: IOException -> IO (Maybe Integer)) $ do ...
```

Though, this can be somewhat verbose. An alternative solution is to specialize `handle`.

```
handleIO :: (IOException -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a
handleIO = handle
```

Then, you can just use `handleIO` whenever you want to handle IO exceptions, without having to spell out the type signature of the handler.

```
saferFileSize path = handleIO (\_ -> return Nothing) $ do ...
```

A third option is to use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, which (among other things) allows you to provide a type annotation for just the argument of a function, allowing the rest to be inferred.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
saferFileSize path = handle (\(_ :: IOException) -> return Nothing) $ do ...
```

Comment: The documentation for the `handle` function on the Haskell website is very unclear about this (at least to entry level people -- the ones who need documentation!) https://wiki.haskell.org/Exception Thanks for the very clear explanation that the compiler just needs us to specify exception types to handle!

Answer (score 4):

RWH is rather old. The `handle` function signature has changed in GHC 6.10 or so.

To use the old version, import `Control.OldException` instead of Control.Exception`. You will get deprecation warnings but the program will compile.

Or you can use the new interface and give the handler an explicit signature, like so:

```
((\ _ -> return Nothing) :: IOException -> IO (Maybe Integer))
```